# Execute multiple INSERT in a pl/sql with dependency

Tags: postgresql, insert, sequence, plpgsql

I use postgresql DB. I want to insert a row to a table and then insert another row to another table which has a foreign key that is related to the first table in one pl/sql execution.

The problem is, when I try to insert the second table row, the database assumes that the row I inserted to the first table doesn't exist, since it hasn't been committed yet. What do I do?

Example:

```
REATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "roomTypeCreate"(character varying, integer)
  RETURNS refcursor AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
curr refcursor;
counter integer;
ids integer[];
current_id integer;
count integer;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO counter FROM "RoomType" WHERE LOWER("type"::character varying) = LOWER($1::character varying);

    IF (counter > 0) THEN
        OPEN curr FOR
            SELECT false AS "Status";
        RETURN curr;
    END IF;

    INSERT INTO "RoomType"("type", "creator", "updater") VALUES ($1, $2, $2);
    SELECT currval('"RoomType_id_seq"') INTO current_id;

    SELECT ARRAY(SELECT id FROM "Rate" WHERE id>0) INTO ids;

    count = 1;

    WHILE ids[count] > 0
    LOOP
        INSERT INTO "RoomTypeRate"("type", "rate", "sun", "mon", "tue", "wed", "thu", "fri", "sat", "creator", "updater") VALUES(current_id, ids[count], 99999999, 99999999, 99999999, 99999999, 99999999, 99999999, 99999999, 0, 0);
        count = count + 1;
    END LOOP;

    OPEN curr FOR
        SELECT true AS "Status";
    RETURN curr;
END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace:

```
INSERT INTO "RoomType"("type", "creator", "updater") VALUES ($1, $2, $2);
SELECT currval('"RoomType_id_seq"') INTO current_id;
```

By:

```
INSERT INTO "RoomType"("type", "creator", "updater") VALUES ($1, $2, $2) returning id into current_id;
```

Comment: Turns out there is nothing wrong with my code, but I made mistake implementing the constraint. I bound it with something else. My bad. But you gave me a new way to implement that. And for that, I thank you.